# highcharts tooltip valueDecimals not working

Tags: highcharts

Sorry for my english.

I have question about highcharts. Please help!

I have chart https://jsfiddle.net/traprap/upmvyjkt/5/

In this chart I have numbers like 0.00000057

But in chart tooltip this numbers converting to 57e-7

```
tooltip: {
    valueDecimals: 8
}
```

not helping

I tried point format, formatter.. but nothing helped
What em I doing wrong?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To format it for a single series you can use the `series.tooltip.pointFormatter` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip.pointFormatter)) in combination with `toFixed` ([API](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)) to show the number with your chosen number of decimals. If you want to format all series you can use `plotOptions.series.tooltip.pointFormatter` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.tooltip.pointFormatter)) with the same function.

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upmvyjkt/29/)):

```
series: [{
    data: price,
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() {
            return '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> '+this.series.name+': <b>'+this.y.toFixed(8)+'</b><br/>'
        }
    },
    // ...
}]
```

This is essentially the default point format of:

```
<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>
```

With variables for series name and the y-value with `toFixed(8)` to show 8 decimals, as an example. This converts the number to a string before it is shown, preventing the scientific notation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i needed.